# Tensorflow 1.14 on Google Collab - No GPU

Tags: linux, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

***TL;DR***

Whats the correct way to install CUDA 10 and replace 10.1 as the CUDA driver on Google Colab?

***Longer:***

Recently Google must have updated some drivers on collab, because CUDA 10.1 is installed, and my project requires which required tensorflow 1.14 (1.15 has some issues with exporting a model) no longer detects the GPU.

When I try to run TD 1.14 on Collab now, I get the following errors:

```
Nov 19, 2019, 9:51:52 AM    WARNING 2019-11-19 14:51:52.917613: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64-nvidia:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
Nov 19, 2019, 9:51:52 AM    WARNING 2019-11-19 14:51:52.917159: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64-nvidia:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
Nov 19, 2019, 9:51:52 AM    WARNING 2019-11-19 14:51:52.916864: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64-nvidia:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
Nov 19, 2019, 9:51:52 AM    WARNING 2019-11-19 14:51:52.916019: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64-
nvidia:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
```

Whats the proper way to fix this?

I have tried:

- Making a soft link from some 10.1 libs to 10.0 so the paths resolve:

```
!ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.10.1.243 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.10.0
!ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusparse.so.10.3.0.243 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusparse.so.10.0
!ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.2.0.243 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.0
!ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcurand.so.10.1.1.243 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcurand.so.10.0
!ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so.10.1.1.243 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so.10.0
```

- Installing Cuda 10 (taken from the Tensorflow Docs)

```
!apt-get --purge remove cuda nvidia* libnvidia-*
!dpkg -l | grep cuda- | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 dpkg --purge
!apt-get remove cuda-*
!apt autoremove
```

```
!wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
!sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
!sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
!sudo apt-get update
!wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
!sudo apt install -y ./nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
!sudo apt-get update

# Install NVIDIA driver
#!sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-418
!sudo apt-get -y installnvidia-driver-418
# Reboot. Check that GPUs are visible using the command: nvidia-smi

# Install development and runtime libraries (~4GB)
#!sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends \
!sudo apt-get install -y \
    cuda-10-0 \
    libcudnn7=7.6.2.24-1+cuda10.0  \
    libcudnn7-dev=7.6.2.24-1+cuda10.0


# Install TensorRT. Requires that libcudnn7 is installed above.
# !sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libnvinfer5=5.1.5-1+cuda10.0 \
!sudo apt-get install -y libnvinfer5=5.1.5-1+cuda10.0 \
    libnvinfer-dev=5.1.5-1+cuda10.0

!apt --fix-broken install
```

And updating the LD_LIBRARY_PATH - but that gets me no where.

Curious what the correct way is to switch to Cuda 10 so I can run TF 1.14?

Comment: > Installing Cuda 10 - this should actually be enough. Do you see the same "Could not dlopen library" messages as before?

Comment: Hi @StefanDragnev - to be clear, do you mean just an `apt-get install cuda-10` ?

I did try that prior and received the same warning - however, its worth trying again.

Comment: Yes, check the exact warning and the exact files present on the library path mentioned in the warning.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. Yes, ive checked it, the instructions followed from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu verbatim, and the contents of collabs cuda-10.1 install differs from the new 10.0 install, which is clearly the issue. So it seems there are some missing dependencies I need to sort out.

Comment: The solution was that Google uses apt holds on Cuda packages. You have to install with the flag ```--allow-change-held-packages``` To ensure it ACTUALLY does it. 

Doh.

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Comment: @vade - *"Not sure why this is getting downvoted"* - The question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site for questions about your package manager. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this - short story, use  --allow-change-held-packages since Google Colab holds CUDA packages. See the bottom for full instructions:

See the edited question above for full solution.

Comment: The relevant GitHub issue is https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/864